# div:focus being used to transition height, clicking on iframe elements reverts transition

Tags: css, iframe, css-transitions

I'm trying to have my website have drop-down divs when clicked, allowing you to examine the inline widgets inside the divs. However, iframe and other elements that aren't strictly images cause the div to transition back to its original state, causing the menu to collapse as though the user had clicked out of the div area.

Here's what I got:

```css
.music-block {
  width: 350px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #bc37ff;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  transition: 0.6s;
}
.music-block:focus {
  max-height: 952px;
}
.music-block:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="music-block" tabindex="1">
  <p>
    <h1>MUSIC</h1>
  </p>
  Text.
</div>
<p>
  <iframe style="border: 0; width: 350px; height: 654px;" src="https://bandcamp.com/EmbeddedPlayer/album=3599654224/size=large/bgcol=ffffff/linkcol=7137dc/transparent=true/" seamless><a href="http://toothbops.bandcamp.com/album/toothbops-ep" target="_blank">toothbops - EP by toothbops</a>
  </iframe>
</p>
</div>
```

Here's an example of what I mean with the menu collapsing when you click on iframes (in this case, a bandcamp widget): http://jsfiddle.net/6m52jxtj/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I can see two posible solutions to your problem, a js way and a css way(there are probably more than that but this comes to mind at the moment :) )

For the **css** way, you'll need to add a `input[tpye='checkbox']` and a `label` on top of the markup, make the label with height and width of the initial music-block and you're good to go: [check out the js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hxup1et/1/)

```
#trigger-music-block{
    display: none;
}
#trigger-music-block + label{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    height: 90px; width: 350px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#trigger-music-block:checked + label + .music-block{
    height: 952px;
}
```

For the **js** way, you can just add a extra class on `.music-block` when a user clicks it, like this:
   [check out js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2jwm3mr/)

```
$('.music-block').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('expanded');
});
```

Comment: I think I prefer the CSS method since it allows you to close the menu again. (I was pretty confused about the difference between the two until I saw you linked the same js fiddle twice, haha) For whatever reason though, this doesn't seem to be working on my actual site. For the life of me, I just can't get it working, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong! I've done exactly what your js fiddle shows, but no luck. :(

Comment: Oh sorry, go ahead and check out the link again, it should work properly now

Comment: Also, if you tried the js approach, make sure you load up jquery library first